# Can I update Python 3.5 without downloading and installing entire new version, eg, 3.5.2?

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade

It seems overkill to download and install 3.5.2 from https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/ to simply updgrade from 3.5.0. Is there a Python command that will update itself?

Mac OS 10.11.6
Python 3.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: do you need to upgrade?

See the [change log](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-5-2). There are no new features introduced in 3.5.2 just various bug fixes. If you are not affected then your time may be better spent elsewhere.

If you do still want to upgrade there is probably no easier way than downloading an upgrade and installing it. Even if you use python to upgrade itself, it would still need to download the same files. There would be no real saving in time.